# What type of tree is this (South Florida)?

Tags: identification, trees

[image]

This tree was found in South Florida, and I am not sure of its species. This image was sent to me and unfortunately I do not have access to any close up of the barks or leaves.

[![trees found in South Florida][2]][2]

Comment: Please read the instructions [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info). In short, only one plant per question and more details that help the readers help you. Your photos are unfortunately very blurry and there are no details like closeups of leaves, bark, etc. that make a reliable identification possible.

Comment: I'm going with Kentia Palm and overgrown Schefflera.